# What does the `s` in `%s` mean in string formatting?

Tags: python

I have just started reading learn python the hard way and I have a question.

for example the code will be

```
name = input("Name?")
print "your name is %s" % name
```

why do we use d or what ever, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `d` in `%d` stands for decimal. `%d` is for formatting numbers. `%s` is for formatting strings. (thus, the example you gave actually doesn't work) Yes, it matters. You need to tell Python where to place the thing after the `%` operator into the string.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` indicates that the value is an integer.  `%s` would be used for strings, which seems better for your example.  See here for more information about string formatting in Python: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 3):

Others have already given the reason for using `%d`.  I would just point out the following method of string formatting is the new standard in python, and if you're writing new code then syntax using `str.format` should be preferred to the % formatting:

```
>>> print "your name is {name}".format(name="Shameer")
your name is Shameer
```

see http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You use %d to print out integers. To print strings, you would use %s.

```
i = 10
print 'The value is %d' % i
name = "Larry"
print 'My name is %s' % name
```

Answer (score 1):

d specifies the variable type for the print function to use. "d" for decimal, "c" for character....

read this

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html